# Unchecked call to filter as a member raw warning как исправить

Tags: java, java-stream, warning

В стриме такой **warning**: "`Unchecked call to filter as a member raw ...`", как исправить?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите слово: ");
        String word = scn.nextLine();
        String[] str = {"Масло", "Вода", "Дерево", "Помидор", "Сельдерей", "Кувшин"};
        List wordList = Arrays.asList(str);
        long countWord = wordList
                .stream()
                .filter(s -> s.equals(word))
                .count();
        if (countWord > 0) {
            System.out.println("Слово найдено");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Слово не найдено");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(str);
```

Comment: блиииин, точно. пропустил, не увидел ... спасибо.

Comment: @Санаев и вместо `Arrays.asList(str).stream()...` лучше использовать `Stream.of(str)...` или `Arrays.stream(str)...`

Comment: @AlexChermenin спасибо за замечание